# Does PropertyChanged only refresh items in view

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've built a desktop application using WPF and XAML. Some graphs in my application contain a significant amount of data points, all grouped into one ObservableCollection. When I refresh items in my application, I also recalculate these data points, and PropertyChanged is called on the collection.

From a performance standpoint, I only want the graphs to re-render if they are actually in view. Does the framework automatically cater for this? I.e. When I call PropertyChanged, the graph is only re-rendered if it's actually in view?

**EDIT**

What I mean by in view, is that the graph will be visible on the screen (Visibility=Visible, Height > 0, Width > 0). It could be inside any control, but without any interaction the user will be able to see the graph.

Comment: In view can mean a few things.  You need to be more clear.

Comment: You could do some benchmarks. Create a view with one graph in and do some timings. Then add some invisible graphs and repeat the timings. See if there's a significant difference.

Comment: Why don't you implement paging and fetch/update only the visible ones?